# SNMP OID for advertised routes by peer

Tags: bgp, snmp, force10

I've found the following SNMP OIDs:

- BGP Peers: .1.3.6.1.2.1.15.3.1.1
- BGP Peer state: .1.3.6.1.2.1.15.3.1.1

But I'm looking for the list of *advertised* routes by peer. Does anybody know of a way to get this via SNMP? My fallback is to use SSH and screen scrape `show` commands, but this seems to be the kind of thing that SNMP was designed for.

If it makes a difference the target platform for this project is FTOS.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin There was only one answer, which I replied to saying that the specified OID wasn't available.

Answer (score 3):

## Cisco

You should be able to use the OIDs under [1.3.6.1.2.1.15.5.1 (bgpPathAttrEntry)](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.2.1.15.5.1#oidContent) for Cisco devices.  There are 2 OIDs in particular that should accomplish what you're looking for.

**[1.3.6.1.2.1.15.5.1.1 (bgpPathAttrPeer)](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.2.1.15.5.1.1#oidContent)** - The IP address of the peer where the path information was learned.

**[1.3.6.1.2.1.15.5.1.2 (bgpPathAttrDestNetwork)](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.2.1.15.5.1.2#oidContent)** - The address of the destination network.

---

## Force10

This information should be obtainable under [1.3.6.1.4.1.6027.20.1.3.4.1 (f10BgpM2PathAttrEntry)](http://cric.grenoble.cnrs.fr/Administrateurs/Outils/MIBS/?oid=1.3.6.1.4.1.6027.20.1.3.4.1).

**[1.3.6.1.4.1.6027.20.1.3.4.1.12 (f10BgpM2AsPathString)](http://cric.grenoble.cnrs.fr/Administrateurs/Outils/MIBS/?oid=1.3.6.1.4.1.6027.20.1.3.4.1.12)** - This is a string depicting the autonomous system path to this network which was received from the peer which advertised it. The format of the string is implementation-dependent, and should be designed for operator readability.

Comment: That looks like it would probably work for IOS, but on FTOS there's no such OID.